# Find empty strings in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to `_search` documents that has some specific value in the field.

```
{
  "query": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
         {"field": {"advs.status": "warn"}}
       ]
      }
  }
}
```

That works find. But when I'm trying to find documents that has empty string in that field, I get this error:

```
ParseException[Cannot parse '' ...
```

and then - long list of what was expected instead of empty string.

I try this query:

```
{
  "query": { 
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {"term": {"advs.status": ""}}
         ]
        }
  }
}
```

It doesn't fails but finds nothing. It works for non empty strings instead. How am I supposed to do this?

My mapping for this type looks exactly like this:

```
{
    "reports": {
        "dynamic": "false",
        "_ttl": {
            "enabled": true,
            "default": 7776000000
        },
        "properties": {
            "@fields": {
                "dynamic": "true",
                "properties": {
                    "upstream_status": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            },
            "advs": {
                "properties": {
                    "status": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "store": "yes"
                    }
                }
            },
            "advs.status": {
                "type": "string",
                "store": "yes"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I enable syntax highlighting for json?

Answer (score 6):

Or another way to do the same thing more efficiently is to use the `exists` filter:

```
"exists" : {
  "field" : "advs.status"
}
```

Both are valid, but this one is better :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this temporary solution which works but isn't optimal - https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/7515

```
PUT t/t/1
{
"textContent": ""
}

PUT t/t/2
{
 "textContent": "foo"
}

GET t/t/_search
{
 "query": {
  "bool": {
   "must": [
    {
      "exists": {
        "field": "textContent"
      }
    }
  ],
  "must_not": [
    {
      "wildcard": {
        "textContent": "*"
      }
     }
   ]
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `must_not` with `missing` in your `bool`:

```
"must_not":{
  "missing":{
    "field":"advs.status",
    "existence":true,
    "null_value":true
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you combine the two answers into one?

Answer (score 1):

If tou want to search for fields containing an empty string, either you change your mapping to set not_analyzed to this particular field or you can use a script filter:

```
"filter": {
  "script": {
    "script": "_source.advs.status.length() == 0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I generally use a filter if the field is not analyzed.  Here is snippet:

```
{
  "filtered": {
    "filter": {
      "term": {
        "field": ""
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

the "missing" does work only for null values or not being there at all. Matching empty string was already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25562877/155708