# Querying a field for empty value

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to query for an empty field.  In SQL parlance, I would do the following:

```
 select * from cars where cartype="Auto" and make="Ferrari" and color="" and model="" and seats in ["", "bench"]
```

I'm doing the following, but I'm getting an error

```
 {
     "query": {
         "bool": {
             "must": [
                 {
                     "match": {
                         "CarType": "Auto"
                     }
                 },
                 {
                     "match": {
                         "Make": "Ferrari"
                     }
                 }
             ],
             "must_not": [
                 {
                     "existence": true,
                     "field": "Color",
                     "null_value": true
                 },
                 {
                     "existence": true,
                     "field": "Model",
                     "null_value": true
                 }
             ]
         }
     }
 }
```

But I get the following:  "Parse Failure [Failed to parse source .... nexted:  query malformed"

I'm following the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18152053/find-empty-strings-in-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [

                {
                 "match": {
                     "CarType": "Auto"
                 }
                }
          ,
          {
                 "match": {
                     "Make": "Ferrari"
                 }

           }
        ], "must_not": [
           {
              "missing":{
                        "field":"Model",
                         "existence":true,
                          "null_value":true
                         }
           },
            {
              "missing":{
                        "field":"Color",
                         "existence":true,
                          "null_value":true
                         }
           }
        ]
    }
}
}
```