# get count of items not listed in a parent-child relationship model in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say that we have employee & department types stored in an elasticsearch index. I have to get the following queries:

1. Count the number of employees that are assigned to any particular department (not a specific department). Note that the employee should just be assigned to some department that's it.
2. Count the number of employees that aren't assigned to any department yet

I am just over simplifying my question with a toy example to give more clarity on what is needed.

Any thoughts/help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Assume that your employees type has a field like this
   `{ "department" : "departmentXYZ" }`
   Then you can use aggregation to get employees assigned to each department as so

`{
    "aggs" :{
        "employees_per_department" : {
            "terms" : {
                "field" : "department"
            }
        }
    }
}`

2. This depends on how you store non-assign value for "department". In case it's empty string then take a look at this
   [Find documents with empty string value on elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25561981/find-documents-with-empty-string-value-on-elasticsearch)

Comment: How about the parent child relationship? I have a has_parent query to get employees with aggregation count on both existing & missing departments.

Comment: Can your clarify the question a bit more? 
The query above should give how many employees belong to each departments, You can also subtract the "hits" total with total doc count in each department bucket to figure out how many employees does not belong to any department.

Comment: Assume this scenario:
There are departments (Parent) that exists & there are many employees(Children) in each department. For simplicity assume one employee is in one department only. Now I need to find the departments that have employees assigned and departments that doesn't have any of the employees assigned yet. Hope that clarifies the question. You can assume that employee stores department reference.