# Elasticsearch exists filter how to make an empty string as null value?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I tried to index a name field to elasticsearch, the name maybe is a string or a empty string(`""`), I want to search all name which contain the empty value, so I use the `exists` filter, but for `exists` filter, the empty value is not a null value.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-exists-filter.html

**query dsl:**

```
{ "filter" : {
                "exists" : { "field" : "name" }
            } 
}
```

How to make the empty string as a null value for elasticsearch `exist` filter? Anyone has good idea?

Comment: You can combine missing filter. 
`"filter": {"missing" : { "field" : "name" }}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term filter should do the job:

```
    {
      "term": {
        "name": ""
      }
    }
```

Just tried it with some of my data and got results, but might depend if your fields are "not-analyzed" (like mine) or not.

Update: Just found this similar question which has a much more detailed answer: [Find documents with empty string value on elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25561981/find-documents-with-empty-string-value-on-elasticsearch)

Comment: I hope to use `exists` filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can try searching by using a `script` filter instead in order to test the length of the string

```
{
  "query": {
    "script": {
      "script": "doc.name.value?.size() == 0"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Scripts are slow and should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: Sebastian is right, his solution works best... only if you have `not_analyzed` field, otherwise it won't work.