# How to find empty string with stempel analyzer

Tags: elasticsearch

I've checked this:
[Find documents with empty string value on elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25561981/find-documents-with-empty-string-value-on-elasticsearch)

Additionally we don't have _source (do not store data) so we can't use this:

```
{"filter": {"script": {"script": "_source._content.length() == 0"}
```

This:

```
{"from": 0, "size": 100, "query":{"term": {"name":""}}}
```

and this:

```
{"filter": {"missing": {"existence": true, "field": "name", "null_value": true}}, "query": {"match_all": {}}}
```

doesn't work!

It seems like stempel store some kind of value on "" (empty string) and it is not "" and not null.