# How can I make a query in elastic search with one space in the query?

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

I am making queries in kibana and am getting errors. Specifically, I want my search query to be just one space. Here is an example: request.query(" "). However, I keep getting an error where it says it there is a parsing exception. Does anyone know how to properly format a string query with one blank space properly so that no error is returned? Thank you in advance!

"query_string":{ "query":"( ) OR (* )",. This is the query. The exception is "type" : "query_shard_exception", "reason" : "Failed to parse query [( ) OR ( *)]",

I have tried using escape characters and whatnot, but it did not seem to help.

Comment: provider you query and exception.

Comment: "_and whatnot_" - Can you be more specific?

Comment: you say you're making a query and getting errors. What is the query query and the error?
Example "request.query(" ")" says nothing to anyone trying to analyze your problem.
Describe exactly what you are doing with example docs and expected behaviors to help the community reproduce the scenario.

Comment: @rabbitbr, "query_string":{
                           "query":"( ) OR (* *)",.   This is the query. The exception is "type" : "query_shard_exception",
          "reason" : "Failed to parse query [( ) OR (* *)]",

Comment: @Sanil - please [edit] your question to provide any additional, relevant information. You can also review the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), as well as [ask].

Comment: @rabbitbr, would you have any idea?

Comment: Do you have an example of a document that you expect to return with the query? I'll try to simulate here.

Comment: I think you can find the answer to your problem in this SOF post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25561981/find-documents-with-empty-string-value-on-elasticsearch