# How to make an elastic search query with a blank space

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana, elastic-stack

I am making queries in kibana and am getting errors. Specifically, I want my search query to be just one blank space. Here is an example: request.query(" "). However, I keep getting an error where it says it there is a parsing exception. Does anyone know how to properly format a string query with one blank space properly so that no error is returned? Thank you in advance!

```
                     {
                        "query_string":{
                           "query":"( ) OR (* *)",
                           "default_field":"contentTitle",
                           "fields":[
                              
                           ],
                           "type":"best_fields",
                           "default_operator":"or",
                           "max_determinized_states":10000,
                           "enable_position_increments":true,
                           "fuzziness":"AUTO",
                           "fuzzy_prefix_length":0,
                           "fuzzy_max_expansions":50,
                           "phrase_slop":0,
                           "escape":false,
                           "auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query":true,
                           "fuzzy_transpositions":true,
                           "boost":1.5
                        }
                     }
The exception is "type" : "query_shard_exception", "reason" : "Failed to parse query [( ) OR (* *)]",



I have tried using escape characters to no avail.
```

Comment: Is this question fundamentally different from this other question you asked one hour earlier: [How can I make a query in elastic search with one space in the query?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75101126/12567365) If so, can you clarify how? Otherwise, you should probably have edited the original question, instead of creating this duplicate one.

Comment: is there any option here to mark a post as duplicate :D ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a query in elastic search with one space in the query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75101126/how-can-i-make-a-query-in-elastic-search-with-one-space-in-the-query)