# Elasticsearch find items with empty field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get items from my index with empty email.

If i search for items with email:"" i get 0 results

```
"query": {
    "term": {
      "email": ""
    }
  }
```

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

if i make a query like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "id": "1234"
    }
  }
}
```

i get an item with email:""

```
"_source" : {
          "id" : "1234",
          "email" : "",
        }
```

My mappings look like so:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "dynamic": "false",
      "properties": {
        "email": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "email_analyzer"
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What can be the cause for this ?

Comment: you should not be using term query for text fields ..
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html#:~:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20term,for%20text%20field%20values%20difficult.

Also this SO thread has an answer for searching for empty text
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25561981/find-documents-with-empty-string-value-on-elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

you need use [exist query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html).

```
{
  "query": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "email"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this with .keyword like the following

```
"query": {
"term": {
  "email.keyword": ""
  }
 }
```